# Asymptotic behavior of a sequence of integrals

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, improper-integrals

I am interested in the asymptotic behavior of sequences $(I_n)$ and $(J_n)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, where

$$I_n = \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-nx^2}}{x^2}\, dx,$$

and

$$J_n = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(1-e^{-x^2})^n}{x^2}\, dx.$$

In the first case, I integrated by parts to obtain

$$I_n = e^{-n} - 2\sqrt{n}\int_{\sqrt{n}}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx= e^{-n}-\sqrt{\pi n} \,\text{erfc}(\sqrt{n}). $$

The asymptotic behavior of the complementary error function is, of course, well-known (using repeated integration by parts) and I found

$$I_n \sim \frac{e^{-n}}{2n}.$$

Now I am having trouble with $J_n$ -- proceeding in the same manner or otherwise.

Comment: Mixing the two notations $\sim$ and $O(\cdots)$ is incorrect.  You either mean $$I_n \sim \frac{e^{-n}}{2n}$$ or $$I_n = \frac{e^{-n}}{2n} + O\left(\frac{e^{-n}}{n^2}\right),$$ and the two are not equivalent.  Also note that the error term is $O(e^{-n}/n^2)$, not $O(1/n^3)$.

Comment: @Antonio Vargas: Thanks very much. Will correct my sloppy use of $\sim$.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making the change of variables $x = y\sqrt{\log n}$ transforms the integral into

$$
J_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}} \int_0^\infty \frac{(1-e^{-y^2\log n})^n}{y^2}\,dy.
$$

For $n > 1$ it can be shown that

$$
\left|\frac{(1-e^{-y^2\log n})^n}{y^2}\right| \leq
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } 0 \leq y < 1 \\
1/y^2 & \text{if } y \geq 1
\end{cases}
\in L_1([0,\infty))
$$

and

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(1-e^{-y^2\log n})^n}{y^2} =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } 0 \leq y < 1 \\
1/e & \text{if } y = 1 \\
1/y^2 & \text{if } y > 1,
\end{cases}
$$

so by the dominated convergence theorem we have

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{(1-e^{-y^2\log n})^n}{y^2}\,dy = \int_1^\infty \frac{dy}{y^2} = 1.
$$

Thus

$$
J_n \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}
$$

as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I'm still grappling with this a bit. I knew that the convergence of $J_n$ was slow so $1/\sqrt{\log n}$ makes sense. But how did you make the determination a priori. Where would this have broken down if you tried $x=yn^{-1}$ or $x=y\log n$. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the integrand has a maximum at $$x_0 = \sqrt{-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{e^{-1/n}}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n}},$$ where $W_{-1}(t)$ is the branch of the Lambert W function which takes real values on the interval $(-1/e,0)$ and tends to $-\infty$ as $t \to 0^-$.  It's known that $W_{-1}(t) \sim \log(-t)$ as $t \to 0^-$, so we should have $$x_0 = \sqrt{-\log\left(\frac{e^{-1/n}}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n}} + o(1) = \sqrt{\log n} + o(1).$$  Consequently, the substitution $x = y\sqrt{\log n}$ should "fix" the maximum at $y_0 = 1$.  This is more or less the reasoning I used to guess the scaling.

Comment: Further, if we had instead chosen some other scaling $x = y a_n$, then **for all** $y > 0$ we would have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(1-e^{\large -y^2 a_n^2})^n}{y^2} = 0$$ if $a_n \ll \sqrt{\log n}$ or $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(1-e^{\large -y^2 a_n^2})^n}{y^2} = \frac{1}{y^2}$$ if $a_n \gg \sqrt{\log n}$.  In the first case all we would be able to deduce is that $J_n \ll \frac{1}{a_n}$ and in the second only that $J_n \gg \frac{1}{a_n}$ (I think).  Only by choosing $a_n \asymp \sqrt{\log n}$ will the boundary between these two limiting behaviors settle to a finite nonzero location.

Comment: I see now. Many thanks.